# Petfinder ajax request with JSON array value issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = 'http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=99392cbf55ee6b2f9b97ed375eca907d&id=WI22&status=A&output=full&format=json';

    $.ajax({

        type : 'GET',

        data : {},

        url : url+'&callback=?' ,

        dataType: 'json',
  
  crossDomain: true,

        success : function(data) {              

         var petfinder = data.petfinder;
   
   console.log(petfinder.pets.pet[0].media.photos.photo['1','$t','x']);
   
  }
 })
})
```

```html
<petfinder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://api.petfinder.com/schemas/0.9/petfinder.xsd">
<header>
<version>0.1</version>
<timestamp>2017-05-30T19:45:18Z</timestamp>
<status>
<code>100</code>
<message/>
</status>
</header>
<lastOffset>25</lastOffset>
<pets>
<pet>
<id>35865497</id>
<shelterId>WI22</shelterId>
<shelterPetId>0349</shelterPetId>
<name>Abby</name>
<animal>Cat</animal>
<breeds>
<breed>Domestic Short Hair-black</breed>
</breeds>
<mix>no</mix>
<age>Senior</age>
<sex>F</sex>
<size>L</size>
<options>
<option>hasShots</option>
<option>noDogs</option>
<option>altered</option>
<option>noCats</option>
<option>housetrained</option>
</options>
<description>
<![CDATA[
My name is Abby! I'm known as the pretty office cat at the Humane Society, but I'm still up for adoption! I'm almost 11 years old but I'm still pretty active for my age! I was surrendered due to my owner having allergies, so it was no fault of my own! That was back in June, 2016! I don't like being picked up due to a medical complication that I have, but other than that I LOVE attention. I LOVE being petted! (Even if I shed sometimes!) I love to cuddle and, quietly, sit with the staff! I'm pretty shy at first, but it won't take me long to warm up to you! I would really enjoy a home that I can spend my golden years at! If you have any questions about me, don't hesitate to call the Humane Society! For more information on this cat or any other animals available at the Humane Society of Barron County please contact us! 715-537-9063, hsbcpets@chibardun.net or www.hsbcshelter.com
]]>
</description>
<lastUpdate>2017-05-27T15:44:18Z</lastUpdate>
<status>A</status>
<media>
<photos>
<photo id="1" size="pnt">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/1/?bust=1488416755&width=60&-pnt.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="1" size="fpm">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/1/?bust=1488416755&width=95&-fpm.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="1" size="x">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/1/?bust=1488416755&width=500&-x.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="1" size="pn">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/1/?bust=1488416755&width=300&-pn.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="1" size="t">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/1/?bust=1488416755&width=50&-t.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="pnt">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/2/?bust=1488416755&width=60&-pnt.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="fpm">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/2/?bust=1488416755&width=95&-fpm.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="x">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/2/?bust=1488416755&width=500&-x.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="pn">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/2/?bust=1488416755&width=300&-pn.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="t">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/2/?bust=1488416755&width=50&-t.jpg
</photo>
</photos>
</media>
<contact>
<address1>1571 Guy Avenue</address1>
<address2/>
<city>Barron</city>
<state>WI</state>
<zip>54812</zip>
<phone>715-537-9063</phone>
<fax>715-637-0108</fax>
<email>hsbcpets@chibardun.net</email>
</contact>
</pet>
```

`{"@size":"x","$t":"http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/35865497/1/?    bust=1488416755&width=500&-x.jpg","@id":"1"}`

I'm trying to use Javascript to access the photos in this XML (returned by the AJAX as JSON). I don't know how to retrieve the images because they are in a weird format as listed above. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated? Or just some direction.

EDIT: `console.log(petfinder.pets.pet[0].media.photos.photo['1','$t','x']);` just returns `undefined`

Comment: Yeah those square brackets with comma delimited values are not a valid way to access properties of a javascript object, what do you expect that line to do?

Comment: I just want to retrieve the first image of the first pet (shown here) in that JSON string. But I'm not sure how to format the line.

Comment: `console.log(petfinder.pets.pet[0].media.photos.photo[0]['$t']);` should output the url.  Those weird key names seem to be because they are more used to serving XML docs, and the @ corresponds to attributes while $t corresponds to the text of the element.

Comment: Thanks! this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first photo of the first pet try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var url = '//api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=99392cbf55ee6b2f9b97ed375eca907d&id=WI22&status=A&output=full&format=json';

  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(
        data
        .petfinder
        .pets
        .pet[0]
        .media
        .photos
        .photo[0]['$t']
      );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

OR

If you want all the photos of the first pet

```js
$(function() {
  var url = '//api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=99392cbf55ee6b2f9b97ed375eca907d&id=WI22&status=A&output=full&format=json';

  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(
        data
        .petfinder
        .pets
        .pet[0]
        .media
        .photos
        .photo
        .map(function (photo) { return photo['$t']; })
      );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

OR

If you want all the photos of all the pets (array of arrays):

```js
$(function() {
  var url = '//api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=99392cbf55ee6b2f9b97ed375eca907d&id=WI22&status=A&output=full&format=json';

  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(
        data
        .petfinder
        .pets
        .pet
        .map(function(pet) {
          return pet
            .media
            .photos
            .photo
            .map(function(photo) {
              return photo['$t'];
            });
        })
      );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @MatthewWalker always welcome. Btw I updated the answer for all 3 possibilities. Check it out :)